# What is the runtime of the following recursive algorithm using the Master Theorem?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, master-theorem

I'm not particularly sure about the runtime of the following algorithm:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n/logn
```

I think this would be `O(n)` by the Master Theorem but I don't know whether `n/logn` is asymptotically equal to `n`. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n` and `log n` are not asymptotically equal. If you try to calculate `lim n / log n` in `n = inf` limit, you can use [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) and end up quickly with `lim n` which is infinity, thus proving that `n` is assymptotically bigger than `log n`.

However, the bigger problem is that, according to few places your problem is ill-conditioned. This case does not satisfy the preconditions for the Master Theorem. Loot at [Example 7](http://people.csail.mit.edu/thies/6.046-web/master.pdf). - exactly your case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the limit of (n/log(n))/n as n tends to infinity. For all n>0, (n/log(n))/n is equal to 1/log(n). 1/log(n) tends to zero as n tends to infinity, not one, so n/log(n) and n are not asymptotically equal.

Comment: This does not answer the question yet.